# Issue with new design: Deleted answers are no longer colored/shaded

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

With the new design, deleted answers are no longer shaded a different color.   This is confusing when trying to review/moderate the site.

Here's an example picture (from this question).   There is no differentiation like there used to be.  I believe there used to be a shaded pink/red background for deleted items.

Using Chrome on Windows 7.

[image]

---

### Fixed!!!!

FYI for those of you who can't see Deleted answers, this is what it now looks like:
[image]

Comment: Probably would be wise to match the deleted scheme with the same we do apparently use for comments. Also can confirm the lack of color on the same specs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have pushed a fix for this to our dev server. The change will go out after our next production build.